# SharePoint on-premise keep prompt on trusted domain

Tags: authentication, 401, 403, trusted-domain

We have a SP2016 on-premise. It is installed on domain `sharepoint.local`. One-way trust is established to our company domain `company.com`. It works fine for last 1 year.

Recently we have rollback the VM snapshot to a week earlier for some troubleshooting. After we rolled back, every user of `company.com` cannot login. The login prompt is prompting forever until user press "cancel" and returned **401 UNAUTHORIZED** page.

But all users of `sharepoint.local` can login without problem.

I never encountered this issue and not sure how to start our troubleshooting. Could you please advise?

P.S. before rollback we are performing some hardening procedure but no password prompt at that moment

Comment: What VM did you roll back, SharePoint, SQL, AD??

Comment: @JoshMcClanahan all of them are rollbacked, then rebooted once.  Only the AD of Sharepoint.com is under our manage so company.com is untouched

Comment: We tried to validate the trust company.com on our AD server. It return "The secure channel (SC) reset on Active Directory Domain Controller \\AD.sharepoint.local of domain sharepoint.local to domain company.com failed with error: Access is denied."

Comment: But we established the same trust between our production farm with same account. The production farm's trust can be validated.

Answer (score 0):

After re-established the trust (re-type the login/password to join domain) between SharePoint.local and Company.com it is fixed. The password is never changed. It seems a rollback of VM snapshot make domain controller think the password is invalid.